Extra Trailing Closure passed in call GIDSignIn and have no idea why, following documentation
I have no idea where to go from here and am struggling to understand my options.
Following documentation here I am using swiftUI and not swift they have:
guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }

// Create Google Sign In configuration object.
let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.configuration = config

// Start the sign in flow!
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: self) { [unowned self] result, error in
  guard error == nil else {
    // ...
  }

  guard let user = result?.user,
    let idToken = user.idToken?.tokenString
  else {
    // ...
  }

  let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                 accessToken: user.accessToken.tokenString)

  // ...
}

This is my code:
func googleSignIn() {
        // Configure Google Sign-In
        guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else {
            print("Failed to get clientID")
            return
        }

        // Create a configuration with the necessary scopes
        let configuration = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)

        // Sign in with Google
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
            with: configuration,
            presenting: getRootViewController())
        { result, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error signing in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let result = result else {
                print("No result found")
                return
            }

            // Successful sign-in, retrieve ID token and access token
            guard let idToken = result.user.idToken?.tokenString,
                  let accessToken = result.user.accessToken?.tokenString else {
                print("Failed to retrieve tokens")
                return
            }

            // Create a Firebase credential with the Google tokens
                let credential = Firebase.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

            // Sign in to Firebase with the Google credential
                Firebase.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Firebase sign-in error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                // Update the isLoggedIn state
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.isLoggedIn = true
                }
                print("Firebase sign-in successful")
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to get the root view controller for presenting the sign-in screen
    func getRootViewController() -> UIViewController {
        guard let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
            .compactMap({ $0 as? UIWindowScene })
            .first?.windows
            .first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController else {
            fatalError("Root view controller not set")
        }
        return rootVC
    }


However I am not able to even build the app because of the error involving an 'extra trailing closure in call' but I am literally just following the documentation. How do I get past this? I am completely lost and I have no idea how I should modify my code to follow the documentation any closer considering I am using SwiftUI and do not see any documentation that applies any more so than this. ChatGPT also gives me the same results.
I tried to use callback instead of trailing closure at end of call, however this yielded in extra argument 'callback' so that was entirely useless.
Any attempt to get around this has also resulted in mismatched expected values and other annoying looping issues which leave me in the same place every time.
I am using imports Firebase and GoogleSignIn.

Your two code blocks are making completely different signIn calls. The first one has signIn(withPresenting: self) {... while your second has signIn(with: configuration, presenting: getRootViewController()) { .... That is the old method signature from 6.2.x.   https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide
